# how to make a table with unique count and count + percentage information

Tags: r, summary, kable

I am a r beginner. Please pardon me if this question sounds silly.

If I have a data set like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=c(21,17,21,19,22,21,26,22,18, 15), 
                sick=c(T,T, F, T,T,F, T,T, T, F), 
                recover=c(T,T,T,F,F,T,T,T,F,F))
```

and I want to make a table out of it, something looks like:
[image]
Note unique count ID is 7, event count is 10. what should I do in order to make such table? Is it possible to make it with kable so I can format it nicely?

Answer (score 0):

We can reshape into 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, grouped by 'name' get the `sum` of 'value' ('EventCount'), and number of distinct elements of 'ID' where the 'value' is TRUE ('PatientCount'), then grouped by those columns, get the 'Total_number_of_all_patients_measured' as the number of 'sick' elements, and number of unique rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, ID))%>% 
   group_by(name) %>% 
   group_by(EventCount = sum(value), PatientCount = n_distinct(ID[value]), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(Total_number_of_all_patients_measured = sum(name == 'sick' & value),
         Total_number_of_all_question_asked = n_distinct(rn))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is is a way to achieve this result without reshape data? My real data are much bigger.